# Which BLE transmitter should I use?

Tags: bluetooth

I'm making a BLE scanner to control locations of my devices. I have a scanner working and it is able to scan BLE devices, but I can't decide what I should buy (I need 150 of them). I just need simplicity and low power consumption. The only thing which I want to scan are MAC address, so I won't need any other features.

I tried to search on eBay, Aliexpress and a few more shops, but I don't exactly know how to formulate a search.

Could you help me with what I'm searching for or give me some specific models?